# How to find the IP which needs a gateway to send and receive packets?

Tags: lan, gateway

In my desktop, I connected my Lan segment is `172.44.1.22` and another PC is `192.181.1.22`. I am pinging from my desktop in cmd. In this, my segment IP `172.44.1.23` and another PC segment IP `192.181.1.23` both are pinging in my pc.

How the packet is sending and receiving these two IPs? Which IP segment needs a default gateway to reach the destination?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to ping a host that is not in the range of your LAN, you need a default gateway.

As an example, **Computer-01** has `172.44.1.1` IP address, **Computer-02** has `172.44.1.2` IP address, **Computer-03** has `192.181.1.1` IP address and **Computer-04** has `192.181.1.2` IP address.

In this case, **Computer-01** doesn't need a gateway if wan to ping **Computer-02**. Because they are in a range of IP addresses. Bear it in mind that the subnet mask is important to recognize the IP address range. The same as **Computer-01** and **Computer-02**, **Computer-03** and **Computer-04** can ping each other without a gateway.

[image]

On the other hand, if **Computer-03** wants to ping **Computer-01**, it needs a gateway because they are not in a range of IP address.

[image]

Note that, It's not necessary that using a different router/switch for each IP address range. You can put all the computers to a single router/switch and add some static route to the router/switch.
Also, you can make VLANs for each range of IP and change router/switch interfaces to trunk mode. Search "Router-on-a-stick" for this one.

IP is a layer-3 protocol on the OSI model hence the router/switch must work on this layer. If you want to config this method, the switch must be a Layer-3 switch.

I hope it was informative for you.

Comment: If  Computer-01 wants to ping  Computer-03 means which gateway we want

Comment: They need their router address as a gateway. For example, **Computer-03** needs `172.44.1.254` and **Computer-02** needs `192.181.1.254`.

Comment: I'll add some better information to the answer later.

Comment: and another one is destination host unreachable (OR) Request time-out means is what and how is coming when i remove my LAN cable

Comment: Check this question out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110622/

Comment: Whether a gateway/router is needed/involved does not necessarily have anything to do with the IP address range of the hosts belongs to. You can have hosts in different *IP subnets* connected to the same switch, and they will still be able to communicate directly as long as they have the necessary routes. They can have prefix /32 and host route to each other as well.

Comment: Also your diagram seems to imply that you need one router for each LAN segment so that the two of them can communicate, but in fact it can be merely two interfaces of a single router.

Comment: @TomYan Thank you for clarification. I've added two routers to understanding better.

Comment: @TomYan Yes, I know. I'll add more information on the body.